# Change Character Color in listing

Tags: listings, color

I want to change some special character's color in listing for example all Parenthesis be red. I don't want to make them keywords they should have different color. is it possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the `literate` key; in the following example. parentheses are typeset in red:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings} 
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    columns=fullflexible,
    literate=*{(}{{\textcolor{red}{(}}}{1}
         {)}{{\textcolor{red}{)}}}{1},
    }
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
    {
      _SetCalibTableName("lorem",100);
      g_Met_strReferenceName1=Met_strReferenceName;
    }
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. it works. just a question what is that number 1 in literate? it should be always 1? what happen if we change it?

Comment: @Karo You're welcome. The last argument (the "1" in my example) specifies the width (in number of characters) that the replacement string (the colored parenthesis) will occupy in the output. Wider strings might require a larger value.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I never understood that. For instance `{…}{...}1` will output the same as `{…}{...}3`.

Comment: @Manuel that is because `fullflexible` was used in my exmaple; try this `\lstset{
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    literate=*{(}{{\textcolor{red}{aa}}}{1}
         {)}{{\textcolor{red}{mmm}}}{1},
    }` and you'll see the difference.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Ah, true. I use `fullflexible` too, so it has no meaning there.